# Order a list according to shuffled rules about elements

Tags: javascript, python

I am writing a layout engine in Javascript and Python but I have a chicken and egg problem. I feel the solution is simple but I cannot see it just yet.

I have a list of widgets with x and y coordinates. They are in a list.

I want to set their x and y according to rules.

The ordering of the rules should not matter - they should produce the same widget ordering regardless of their order. This is the problem I have right now. I cannot seem to get the ordering to be independent of the ordering of the rules. The same set of rules in any order should produce the same widget Xs and Ys.

My rules look like this:

```
[
    "blogSidebar hasSize 4",
    "menu above heroPost",
    "blah rightOf heroPost",
    "featuredPosts above blogs",
    "header above menu",
    "heroPost above featuredPosts",
    "menu hasSize 12",
    "heroPost hasSize 6",
    "menu",
    "featuredPosts",
    "heroPost",
    "header above featuredPosts",
    "header",
    "blogs hasSize 8",
    "blogSidebar rightOf blogs",
    "featuredPosts above blogs",
    "blah2 leftOf blah",
    "header above heroPost"
]
```

- Can ignore the hasSize and single word declaration rules
- RightOf means that the .x coordinate of a widget should be +1 to the
  other one
- LeftOf means the .x coordinate should be -1 to the other
  one
- Above means that .y coordinate should be -1 to the other one

I am trying to set widget x and y coordinates from this list of rules which should be in an arbitrary order.

**How do I go about mapping the rules to the widgets x and ys so that the order of the rules doesn't matter?**

My code is here: https://github.com/samsquire/additive-guis/blob/master/layout/layouter2.html#L479 You can run it in the browser. Shuffling which is what I am using to test rule order independence is currently commented out on line 479.

A solved problem, which I asked about on python Stackoverflow chat is how to solve equations like this:

widgetA.x < widgetY.x < widgetZ.x

I use this algorithm: https://github.com/samsquire/additive-guis/blob/master/INEQUALITY-PROBLEM.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to run the addRule algorithm twice. Once as rules are being encountered and again at the end to fix-up any errors accumulated by running the algorithm.

You can find the [revised algorithm here](https://github.com/samsquire/additive-guis/blob/40bb122aa4e7dfc01e172a31d1142303e6e567d9/layout/layouter2.html#L334):